# Indexing Date via Loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, indexing

I am attempting to determine where dates are located in a matrix with the following code:

```
#portret is a list of daily returns for three different stocks from 1980-01-01 to 2010-12
#13.These dates are listed in the first column of the portret data frame
library(quantmod)
library(FRAPO)
getSymbols(c("F","AA","IBM"),from="1980-01-01", to="2010-12-31")
port=cbind(F$F.Adjusted,AA$AA.Adjusted,IBM$IBM.Adjusted)
portret=returnseries(port,"discrete",trim=TRUE)
portret=data.frame(index(portret),coredata=portret)
date.list=seq.Date(as.Date("1990-10-01"),as.Date("2010-10-01"),by="month")
length(date.list)
#this equals 241
date.index=matrix(0,241,2)
for(i in 1:241){
    date.index[i,]=which(portret[,1]==as.character(date.list[i]),arr.ind=TRUE)}
```

I keep receiving this error: 
  replacement has length zero

Please advise.

Comment: It fails at `i = 3`. `as.character(date.list[3])` is not found in `portret[,1]`. Try `sum(portret[,1] == as.character(date.list[i]))`. You'll see it's 0. It's not clear what you are trying to do. You have the dates already in portret. What are you trying to do with date.list?

Comment: I see... What I am doing in solving for minvar port of portret for every trading day and this I am going back through and collecting specific month values based on dates.  So I will have a row of stock weights that I need to reference to the date of portret.  That prob isnt the best way of explaining it but thank you for identifying the issue.

Comment: Have a look at http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/5th-of-month-working-day-td1016705.html You problem seems similar.

Comment: That would be perfect!  Thanks for the tip.  I am new to R so I had no idea.

Comment: Look at functions in the timeDate package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timeDate/

Answer (score 0):

the error is because the conditional statement evaluated to `FALSE`.

ie:

```
  x      <- 1:5
  x[[2]] <- which(FALSE)
```

---

The problem is that not all dates in `date.list` are in `portret[, 1]`.
Instead, try this inside your `for` loop:

```
w <- which(portret[,1]==as.character(date.list[i]),arr.ind=TRUE)
date.index[i,] <- ifelse(identical(w, integer(0)), c(NA, NA), w)
```

But better still:

```
date.index <- 
  sapply(as.character(date.list), function(D) 
      {w <- which(portret[,1]==D, arr.ind=TRUE);
      ifelse(identical(w, integer(0)), c(NA, NA), w)})
```

Comment: This works really well.  I just need to see if I can tailor this code to move up a date or down a date if it is NA.  I imagine I can accomplish this in the ifelse portion of the code.

Comment: would reading it all in, then just removing the rows with `NA` work?